# Close all open folders and subfolders with one click

Tags: windows-8

If the option "Open each folder in new window" is active, there are opening several folders for each subfolder you doubleclick to open.

I once saw a shortcut, that closes all these windows, opened in that manner at once.

something like: Shift+Alt+click on the X

Is there such a shortcut in Windows 8?

Comment: You should be able to right-click the icon in the taskbar and choose "Close all windows".

Comment: I don't want to close **all** explorer windows, just the one folder and all its parents

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Shift` + `Click on the X` on the latest child folder should close the current folder as well as all of the parent folder(s).

For example if I have the following folders open in separate windows I would just have to `Shift` + `Click on the X` on `C:\Users` to close all three folders.

`My Computer` - `C:\` - `C:\Users`